# Check li click value

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, listitem

I m using two list items with link. Now I want to check which link was clicked from the client side. Here is my code:

```
  <ul id="navtabs">
            <li id="basic" runat="server" class="cat-item cat-item-6 current-cat"><a href="#">new</a></li>
            <li id="new" runat="server" class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="#">old</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I want to check which item am click whether basic or new

```
if(this.basic.clicked ==true)
{
   do something
}
else
{
  do something
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: ..is this C# or javascript? "Client side" doesn't refer to C#..

Comment: This is C#. I want to read what link is clicked..

Comment: Instead of using html tags use asp.net linkbutton to postback and then u know which one was clicked.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are suing Web forms then,

1. The the control which are suing must be server control
2. If it is a link the put runat="server" and id of the control
3. Create on click event of every link.

But what is the purpose of those link is not clear.
What action do you want to take on the click must be clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick for it. You can do this with help of jQuery, one hidden field & one hidden asp button.

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Hidden Button" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnLIClicked" runat="server" />
```

Now jQuery part, in ready event

```
    $().ready(function() {
        $("#Button1").hide();//hiding the button through jQuery

        $("#basic").click(function(){
            $("#hdnLIClicked").val("basic");
            $("#Button1").click();
        });
        $("#new").click(function(){
            $("#hdnLIClicked").val("new");
            $("#Button1").click();
        });
    });
```

Or you can give a common class to all your list items, if there are more list items, like you already have a common class for both of your list items. i.e "cat-item".

```
    $().ready(function() {
        $("#Button1").hide();//hiding the button through jQuery

        $(".cat-item").click(function(){
            $("#hdnLIClicked").val($(this).attr("id"));
            $("#Button1").click();//this will fire the hidden button event on server side.
        });
    });
```

And you'll have which 'li' was clicked in the hiddenfield.

On backend, handle the button click event like this.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (hdnLIClicked.Value == "basic")
        {
            //handle your logic for basic here...
        }
        else if (hdnLIClicked.Value == "new")
        {
            //handle your logic for new here...
        }
    }
```

Hide the button through jQuery, don't set its property *Visible="false"*, or the button won't get rendered on client side.

Enjoy ;)...